# Is there a haloalkane for astatine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

I'm studying organic chemistry, and I noticed that there are fluoro-, chloro-, bromo-, and iodoalkanes. However, there are none for Astatine. Could someone shed some light on this, and what it would be called?

Comment: Astatine is so unstable that for most chemical purposes you may just as well consider it non-existent.

Comment: The fact that you're unlikely to come across an organoastatine compound doesn't make the question unimportant or uninteresting; astatine derivatives have definitely been made, and there are certainly naming conventions.

Comment: There also should more be carbon-hydrogen astatine compounds like for example methyl astatide (CH3At) , dimethyl astatide (CH2At2) and so on. But it is highly radioactive like all astatine compounds,so it might just break down into its elements

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Part of the reason why there has been very little research done on organoastatine chemistry is the extreme radioactivity of astatine; the half-life of $\ce{^210At}$, the longest-lived isotope, is about 8 hours. However, the element can be incorporated into organic compounds (e.g., via a destannylation reaction).<sup>1</sup>

In organic chemistry, the prefix is "astato-", as in astatobenzene or 3-astatotamoxifen, both of which have been synthesized.<sup>1,2</sup> This is analogous to "fluoro-", "chloro-", and so on. As a general term, astatine compounds can be referred to as astatides (e.g. aryl astatides, analogous to aryl fluorides, chlorides, etc.).<sup>1</sup>

The aforementioned synthesis of 3-astatotamoxifen is shown below.

[image: 3-astatotamoxifen synthesis]

As for inorganic nomenclature, astatine can be denoted with the prefix "astatido-"; this follows from the IUPAC Red Book for nomenclature of inorganic compounds.

---

1. Milius, R. A., W. H. McLaughlin, R. M. Lambrecht, A. P. Wolf, J. J. Carroll, S. J. Adelstein, and W. D. Bloomer. *Appl. Radiat. Isot.* **1986,** *37* (8), 799-802.
2. Samson, G., and A. H. W. Aten. *Radiochimica Acta* **1970,** *13* (4), 220-221.

Answer (score 5):

There's a page for it on Wikipedia. Have a go at reading it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_astatide

There's something interesting here. With Astatine being so electropositive, dissociation of $\ce{HAt}$ could form $\ce{H-}$ and $\ce{At+}$. If you tried to add this to propene, you would most probably get 1-astatopropane rather than 2-astatopropane.

Don't push your luck too far. Before you can call your fellow chemistry buddy and say "Hey look here! This is 1-astatopropane!" It's gone. That's because Astatine is highly radioactive:

$$\ce{^{210}_{85}At -> ^{206}_{83}Bi + ^{4}_{2}He}$$

With a half life of 8.1 hours, your beloved 1-astatopropane is going to decay away, leaving only a trail of alpha particles, and a few gamma photons. *sob*

Actually, for that matter even $\ce{HAt}$ isn't going to be there for long.

Comment: The logical follow-up question: what happens to the 1-astatopropane molecule once its astatine has become bismuth?  Could you conceivably use this to wedge bismuth atoms into molecules where they wouldn't normally go?

Comment: @zwol A nuclear decay releases so much energy compared to a chemical bond that chemistry can be ignored when considering nuclear decay. In practice you'll probably end up with ionized bismuth, hydrogen and helium after decay.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Not really https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/what-happens-to-a-radioactive-carbon-dioxide-molecule-when-its-carbon-14-atom-de