# Carbon 14 in organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, isotope

A small amount of natural carbon is $\ce{^{14}C}$.  This is radioactive and decays to $\ce{^{14}N}$.  This is exploited in radiocarbon dating.

This $\ce{^{14}C}$ is taken up by living organisms.  I know that natural biochemical processes can be sensitive to isotopes but I expect that the $\ce{^{14}C}$ can occur in any context where $\ce{^{12}C}$ could occur.  (Please correct me if I am wrong here.)

So, $\ce{^{14}C}$ might occur as part of the backbone of a fatty acid:

$$. . . \ce{-CH2-{^{14}C}H2-CH2 -} . . .$$

When the $\ce{^{14}C}$ decays, this will become:

$$. . . \ce{-CH2-NH-CH2 -} . . .$$

(I assume one of the hydrogens would be lost.)

Are any of these unusual compounds stable or do they promptly react in some way?

Are they studied?

Do they have any interesting properties?

Comment: I wonder if it can decay _in-place_ i.e. in the middle of a compound the way you have depicted, without breaking the chain itself. The decay process is generally accompanied by a loss of heat (due to mass-defect) so the extra energy must manifest itself as kinetic energy of the daughter nuclei or heat, breaking the chemical bonds either way.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Will the result immediately break down: that's my question.  I am reasonably sure that the $\ce{^{14}C}$ does not know or care that it is inside a fatty acid and hence will be liable to decay.  I had in mind the $\ce{^{18}F}$-FDG used in PET scans though that is the reverse: an unusual molecule becomes a common one when the $\ce{^{18}F}$ decays to $\ce{^{18}O}$.

Comment: Related: [What happens to a radioactive carbon dioxide molecule when its carbon-14 atom decays?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/65809/7951)

Comment: @Loong Thanks.  "The decay energy of 14C is unusually low" but, nonetheless, it seems likely that the bonds will be broken.  However, at least according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fludeoxyglucose_(18F), the decay of $\ce{^{18}F}$ in $\ce{^{18}F}$-FDG does not break the molecule apart.

Comment: @badjohn I quickly scanned the reference given at wp, and I think it says nothing of the kind. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK23335/ Total own research, respectively own imagination of the wp author.

Comment: @Karl So, this part is probably incorrect: "After 18F-FDG decays radioactively, however, its 2-fluorine is converted to 18O−, and after picking up a proton H+ from a hydronium ion in its aqueous environment, the molecule becomes glucose-6-phosphate labeled with harmless nonradioactive "heavy oxygen" in the hydroxyl at the C-2 position."

Comment: @badjohn It's most probably imo incorrect, and definitively does not belong on wp without a proper reference. Same sentence can be found on de:wp. ;-)