# Do radioisotopes emitted particles influence their chemistry?

Tags: isotope, radioactivity

Supposedly, a isotopes have the same chemistry, i.e. how they bond to other atoms. Is this true for radioisotopes?  I can imagine a nucleus emitting particles that interact with existing bonds in its outer shell, i.e. it may break an existing bonds, or reconfigure them. Does this happen at all?

Comment: The recoil from a nuclear reaction is frequently enough to break a bond.

Comment: The radiated particle can break a _thousand_ bonds and still keep running. Of course it does influence chemistry a great deal. Radiation chemistry is a thing, after all.

Comment: An atom that transmutes into another element .... is extremely unlikely to have the same chemistry afterwards.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/what-happens-to-a-radioactive-carbon-dioxide-molecule-when-its-carbon-14-atom-de

Comment: You asked about *nucleus emitting particles*. As Karl pointed out that would tend to transmute the atom to another element. There are two forms of radioactivity that would allow an element to stay the same element - neutron emission, and a metastable nucleus which emits a gamma ray.